# Unable to get Rviz to display robot

Tags: rviz, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been working on a robot of my own design and I have it working with hardware but when I try to visualize it in Rviz it's not working. [code repository](https://github.com/lutinplunder/shelob_syropod)

When I run the display.launch the robot displays correctly.

```
<launch>
  <arg
    name="model" />
  <arg
    name="gui"
    default="true" />
  <param
    name="robot_description"
    textfile="$(find shelob_syropod)/robot/shelob_syropod.urdf" />
  <param
    name="use_gui"
    value="$(arg gui)" />
  <node
    name="joint_state_publisher"
    pkg="joint_state_publisher"
    type="joint_state_publisher" />
  <node
    name="robot_state_publisher"
    pkg="robot_state_publisher"
    type="robot_state_publisher" />
  <node
    name="rviz"
    pkg="rviz"
    type="rviz"
    args="-d $(find shelob_syropod)/rviz/urdf.rviz" />
</launch>
```

However when I use the shelob_highlevel.launch.

```
<!-- -*- xml -*- -->

<launch>

  <!-- Define ancillary node launch arguments -->
  <arg name="syropod" default="shelob" />
  <arg name="config" default="shelob" />
  <arg name="gait" default="gait" />
  <arg name="auto_pose" default="auto_pose" />
  <arg name="control" default="joy" />
  <arg name="rviz" default="true" />
  <arg name="gazebo" default="false" />
  <arg name="plot" default="false" />
  <arg name="reconfigure" default="false" />
  <arg name="logging" default="false" />

  <!-- Set package name -->
  <arg name="package" value="(find $(arg syropod)_syropod)" />

  <!-- Control method (joypad or keyboard)-->
  <node if="$(eval control == 'joy')" pkg="joy" type="joy_node" name="joystick"/>
  <rosparam if="$(eval control == 'key')" file="$(find syropod_keyboard_control)/config/dell_key_map.yaml" command="load"/>
  <node if="$(eval control == 'key')" pkg="syropod_keyboard_control" type="syropod_keyboard_control_node" name="key" output="screen"/>
  <node if="$(eval control == 'rqt')" pkg="syropod_rqt_reconfigure_control" type="syropod_rqt_reconfigure_control" name="rqt_control" output="screen"/>
  <node if="$(eval control == 'rqt')" pkg="rqt_reconfigure" type="rqt_reconfigure" name="rqt_reconfigure" output="screen"/>

  <!-- Remote Start-->
  <node if="$(eval arg('control') not in ('rqt'))" pkg="syropod_remote" type="syropod_remote" name="syropod_remote" output="screen">
    <param name="publish_rate" value="10"/>
    <param name="imu_sensitivity" value="3"/>
    <param name="invert_compass" value="true"/>
    <param name="invert_imu" value="true"/>
  </node>

  <!-- Highlevel controller related parameters -->
  <rosparam file="$$(arg package)/config/$(arg gait).yaml" command="load"/>
  <rosparam file="$$(arg package)/config/$(arg auto_pose).yaml" command="load"/>
  <rosparam file="$$(arg package)/config/$(arg config).yaml" command="load"/>

  <!-- Highlevel Controller Start -->
  <node name="shc" pkg="syropod_highlevel_controller" type="syropod_highlevel_controller_node" output="screen" />

  <!-- Launch RVIZ with default SHC config -->
  <group if="$(arg rviz)">
    <param name="/syropod/parameters/debug_rviz" value="true"/>
    <param
            name="robot_description"
            textfile="$(find shelob_syropod)/robot/shelob_syropod.urdf" />
    <node name="rviz" pkg="rviz" type="rviz" args="-d $(find syropod_highlevel_controller)/rviz_cfg/shelob_SHC_display.rviz"/>
  </group>

  <!-- Launch Gazebo Simulation -->
  <group if="$(arg gazebo)">
    <param name="/syropod/parameters/individual_control_interface" value="true"/>
    <include file="$$(arg package)/launch/$(arg syropod)_gazebo.launch"/>
  </group>

  <!-- Launch ancillary nodes if requested -->
  <node if="$(arg plot)" name="rqt_plot" pkg="rqt_plot" type="rqt_plot"/>
  <node if="$(arg reconfigure)" name="reconfigure" pkg="rqt_reconfigure" type="rqt_reconfigure"/>

  <!-- Logging -->
  <group if="$(arg logging)">
    <include file="$$(arg package)/launch/$(arg syropod)_log.launch">
      <arg name="bagfile_name" value="$(arg syropod)" />
      <arg name="path_to_log_directory" value="$(find package)/logs"/>
      <arg name="record_all" value="true" />
    </include>
  </group>

</launch>
```

I get TF error

> No transform from [AL_coxa_link] to [odom_ideal]

on all but the base_link. If I add the joint_state_controller and robot_state_controller lines from the display.launch the model displays and the Joints move correctly but the links/visuals don't move
[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/401566/unable-to-get-rviz-to-display-robot/) by [lutinplunder](https://answers.ros.org/users/62191/lutinplunder/) on ROS Answers with karma: 55 on 2022-05-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I figured it out. I needed to launch Rviz with Gazebo in order to load the controllers, use sim time and update the python code for the controllers to use python3. I'm still having a problem with the controllers loading with the .launch but I can use RQT to load them after Gazebo starts.

---

Originally posted by [lutinplunder](https://answers.ros.org/users/62191/lutinplunder/) with karma: 55 on 2022-05-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Joe28965](https://answers.ros.org/users/50769/joe28965/) on 2022-05-30**:
If you've answered your own question, please accept your own answer by clicking the grey check mark on the left.